# How do I update an existing C++ SDL application to be published on Windows Store?

Tags: c++, windows-store-apps, sdl, publish

I have a project which I have been working on for a few years now. I would like to publish this to Windows Store. I am using C++ and SDL.

What does Windows Store require from an application so that it can be uploaded and used in the Store?

Comment: You can start here https://dev.windows.com/en-us/bridges

Comment: @TonyO Thank you. I am reading